# Distinction 'limit to infinity' and 'inclusive infinity' for bitstrings

Tags: infinity, formal-languages, bit-strings

How to describe the difference: Take a digit string of countable infinite 0's and construct a collection of all such strings where we allow a 1 at any position with finitely preceding digits, or allow a 1 at any digit position.

e.g.:

```
finite choice: [(0|1) -> lim_inf] ++ [0 -> inf]
infinite choice: [(0|1) -> lim_inf] ++ [(0|1) -> inf]
```

such that i can also choose to write:

```
finite choice: [(0|1) -> lim_inf]
infinite choice: [(0|1) -> inf]
```

The collection of finite choice bitstrings is countable infinite, whereas the collection of infinite choice bitstrings is uncountable infinite.

The amount of choice / "(0|1)" digit positions is finite in the first collection, the amount of choice digit positions is countable infinite in the second collection.

I do not approve of the above notation, as it is unclear about how lim_inf and inf differ.

I thought also about writing this difference as "*there exists some position in [(0|1) -> inf], which has infinite preceding digits - whereas [(0|1) -> lim_inf] does not*", but this is not necessarily true. Consider for example the natural numbers, which are countable infinite, yet no number has infinite preceding (other) numbers.

References are also welcome.

P.S. ++ is the list concatenation operator,
A -> B stands for A repeating B times, where A is allowed to create "branches".

e.g.:

```
[0 -> 5] = [00000]

[(0|1) -> 2]++[1 -> inf] = 
    {[01]++[111..], [11]++[111..], [00]++[111...], [10]++[111..]}
```

yet :

```
[0->inf] = [000..]
[0->lim_inf] = [000..]
[(0|1)->inf] =/= [(0|1)->lim_inf]
```

Thus inf and lim_inf should be of different sizes.

Comment: Is `A->B` the set of functions from A to B and is `++` the set union operator?

Comment: ah yes, i forgot to clarify. ++ is the concatenate operator for appending A to B (since we are talking about a bitstring order is of importance). A -> B, is the ill-defined operator i am looking to improve - where B is some kind of position towards which A is repeated. I will edit my post for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Every digit position has finitely many preceding positions.

Comment: Which is why i said my initial approach of formulating the difference between having lim_inf digits and inf digits is flawed. I do still think there is a basis for making the distinction between lim_inf and inf.